# Capistrano - How to not restart on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

My current Capistrano version is 2.15.5

Whenever I run the `deploy` task, it triggers a `restart` automatically.

This is expected as per the [doc](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#deploy).

```
------------------------------------------------------------
cap deploy
------------------------------------------------------------
Deploys your project. This calls both `update' and `restart'.
```

In my case, I want to manually run the `restart` task. I don't want `deploy` to run `restart`.

So my questions is:

> Is there a way to override this behavior and not trigger the `restart` task in deploy.

Comment: Please leave a suggestion so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, the `deploy` task just does an `update` followed by a `restart`. If you don't want to do a restart, then just call the update task (i.e. `cap update`) instead of the deploy task.

If you have before or after hooks registered against deploy they would no longer be called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do have before and after hooks against deploy, that is why I wanted to not `restart` on `deploy` instead of doing an `update`.